# I am trying to get icons next to file names in ListView qt, FileIconProvider is giving an error

Tags: qt, icons

```
QFileInfo fileinfo(files.at(i));
QFileIconProvider iconprovider;
QIcon icon = iconprovider.icon(fileinfo);
QStandardItem *s_item=new QStandardItem(icon,temp.at(i));
```

`files.at(i)`, contains an absolute path to an image file. I am not to able use `FileIconProvider` to get the icon for the file/.

> C:\Users\Mohan\Documents\sample\mainwindow.cpp:32: error: aggregate 'QFileIconProvider iconprovider' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
>           QFileIconProvider iconprovider;
>                             ^
>   the above error is printed

Comment: Did you `#include` it?

Comment: `#include <QFileIconProvider>`

Comment: its working now, thank you.